# Why all the taxiway construction at PHL?

Tags: taxiing, airport-design

Perusing [Google Earth](https://www.google.com/earth/) around Philadelphia, I noticed some new taxiway construction at [PHL/KPHL](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KPHL).  The "time machine" feature of GE shows this to be new (latest imagery data is May 2016)--the paved areas in the red circle below don't appear in past aerial imagery.

What are all these paved areas for?  Are they extending 10R/27L?

[image: PHL construction (Google Earth)]
From Google Earth

Note:  The [Google Maps image for this area](https://www.google.com/maps?ll=39.87200,-75.23721&z=15&t=h) shows an older aerial image (without all that extra concrete).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the KPHL website](http://www.phl.org/Pages/Passengerinfo/construction_areas.aspx)

> **Realign Taxiway H and Establish Taxiway EE (North)**
>
> This is the first phase of a multi-phased project to provide a 1,494
>   linear-foot extension of Runway 9R-27L, construction of associated
>   eastside taxiways and hold pads.  In this phase a new Taxiway EE will
>   establish a connection between Taxiways H and K and Taxiway H will be
>   realigned between Taxiway EE and the existing Taxiway D.
>
> *Projected completion date: August 2016*

As well as,

> **9R-27L Extension - Site Prep, Utility, & Fuel Line Relocation**
>
> This is the first phase of a multi-phased project to provide a 1,494
>   linear-foot extension of Runway 9R-27L, construction of associated
>   eastside taxiways and hold pads.  In this phase a new Taxiway EE will
>   establish a connection between Taxiways H and K and Taxiway H will be
>   realigned between Taxiway EE and the existing Taxiway D.
>
> *Projected completion date: October 2016*

The imagery predates the projected completion dates so it makes sense.